# Parsing local json file

Tags: json, swift

I have this JSON file:

```
{
    "People" : [{
        {
            "Name": "Jack"
            "Age": 130,
            "Job": "Doctor",
        },
        {
            "Name": "Mark"
            "Age": 45,
            "Job": "Engineer",
        },
        {
            "Name": "Sarah"
            "Age": 27,
            "Job": "Designer",
        },

    }]
}
```

Here is how I parse it using a helper function:

```
static func parseJson(file: String) -> [String: Any] {
        let jsonFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "json")
        let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: jsonFile!)
        let jsonDictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData! as Data, options: [])

        return jsonDictionary as! [String: Any] <-- Error
    }
```

Then when I try to initialise it:

```
let data = parseJson(file: "People")  as! [String: Any]
print(data["people"])
```

I get this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

What am I doing wrong here? I followed this [tutorial by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37)

Comment: jsonlint.com says invalid JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always validate your JSON using some validator.

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Correct JSON format:

```
{
    "People" : [
        {
            "Name": "Jack",
            "Age": 130,
            "Job": "Doctor",
        },
        {
            "Name": "Mark",
            "Age": 45,
            "Job": "Engineer",
        },
        {
            "Name": "Sarah",
            "Age": 27,
            "Job": "Designer",

    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this website will definitely help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems:

1. You have an extra set of curly braces as you begin and end your array.

Line 2 should be `"People": [` <--NO {

Line 18 should be `]` <--NO }

2. Once you do that, you also have an unnecessary trailing comma after Sarah, which will throw off some JSON parsers.

Comment: You also missed commas after "Jack", "Mark", and "Sarah"; that will throw off the JSON parser.  Also, you should remove the commas after the job names--the last property of the objects--i.e. `"Job": "Designer"` <--NO ,

Comment: Yup, some silly typos. First time I'm dealing with JSON format.
Thanks for the help.